# Parameter 0 of constructor required a bean of type

Tags: java, spring-boot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdwJP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDGwg.png)

I still don't know what to do(I tried with the Repository annotation over UserRepository - the error is the same).
Error message:
`Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-03-14 09:04:54.626 ERROR 7236 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.sprintbootdemo.service.UserService required a bean of type 'com.example.sprintbootdemo.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.sprintbootdemo.repository.UserRepository' in your configuration.

Process finished with exit code 1
`

Comment: Always add code as text not as link to an image please

Comment: please read  [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/16320675) **and** its answer

Comment: thx u , i'll do that next time

Answer (score 0):

You can try with: @Repository annotation on the top of your UserRepository
interface

Comment: read up to the end (i already tried)

Comment: on 2nd picture not shown @Repository annotation, this is because, I wrote!